# chrome.history.search API and HistoryItem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there anyway to identify history items from other devices within the chrome.history API?

The HistoryItem object does not contain this information, is there another call to make per HistoryItem element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looks like a feature was added last year to show the history from all devices if the "Instant extended API" flag was set](https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/PCvtNK45EAH) ([source](https://codereview.chromium.org/12605010/)).

For a while users could disable this flag but recently Google removed this as an option. If I'm reading this correctly, this is now included in the standard Chrome build. Perhaps to be sure, you could check if the flag is set. Nevertheless, if this is the case, then the history searched/returned via the API should include all devices. However, looking over the API docs, it looks like you cannot isolate the history for a specific device.

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=326788
- [Google Removes Enable Instant Extended API Flag in Chrome](http://techdows.com/2013/12/chrome-enable-instant-extended-api-flag-not-appearing.html)

---

**Source Code Digging**

Found this comment in the [code for the history page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/out/Debug/gen/chrome/IDR_HISTORY_HTML_history.html&q=data-devicename&sq=package%3achromium&dr=C&l=805). Not sure if feasible, but maybe you could manually check the `data-devicename` attribute for each history item to determine the device.

```
/* Styles for the action menu of visits that come from other devices, triggered
   by setting the "data-devicename" attribute of the menu. */

#action-menu[data-devicename]:not([data-devicename='']) {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

[This file contains the code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/out/Debug/gen/chrome/IDR_HISTORY_JS_history.js&sq=package%3achromium&dr=C) that sets the above `data-devicename` value.

Comment: I will investigate that code further, however, when I do a search query on the chrome.history API the values returned are from all devices but I cannot distinguish which are from other devices or which device they are from. I will have to dig into chrome source some more as the default chrome history page can distinguish this so there must be a way to acheive it.

Comment: [You could use `chrome.sessions`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions.html) which appears to allow one to pull the last session per device. That won't be the entire history but at least show what pages were visited per the device.

Comment: @click2install I added some links to the source where the `data-device` value gets set on the history page. That might prove helpful.

Comment: I have tracked down the code the history tab uses (history.js) with help from your links. I should be able to implment now. Thank you.

Comment: Chrome uses `chrome.send('queryHistory', args)` to get the history for the history tab. This is the only call that is populating `deviceName` and `deviceType`. So I figured a hack would be to load the history frame into a hidden iframe and read the DOM from there but chrome does not allow `chrome://history-frame` to be loaded by anything but a `chrome.tabs.create` or `chrome.tabs.update` call. In short, it doesn't look possible ... I am still digging into JavaScript though to be certain.